# How do SSE listeners impact read operation limits to fireabase realtime database?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, server-sent-events

I am building an application that uses SSE to listen to changes in specific references in firebase realtime database. I am wondering how the SSE listener impacts read operations. Does it count as 1 read when its initialized, 1 read every time there is an update or does it work some other way? If anyone has knowledge of SSE and read/write operations, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase's Realtime Database does not charge for the number read operations, but only for the bandwidth the data that you read. The bandwidth consists of two parts:

1. The size of the JSON data you read.
2. The cost of establishing a connection over HTTPS.

If you create 5 SSE listeners that each reach 100KB, that is the same amount of JSON read as when a single SSE listener reads 500KB. There will be 5 times more cost of establishing a connection though. To determine the exact cost, I recommend running a few tests and measuring the bandwidth usage.